# AWS CloudSearch Suggesters (Auto-complete)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, autosuggest, search-suggestion, amazon-cloudsearch

Trying to get suggestions suggested matches from AWS CloudSearch using their suggesters feature. I have configured the suggester through the CloudSearch portal which is self-explanatory.

Here is the following request I am trying to make with python `requests`:

```
endpoint = "http://MY-SEARCH-ENDPOINT.us-west-2.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/suggest"
params = {'q' : 'wed', 'suggester' : 'keyword_suggester'}
r = requests.get(endpoint, params = params)
```

Which returns response:

```
r.json()
{u'status': {u'rid': u'9b/Rjq4p/wEK1YX2', u'time-ms': 2}, u'suggest': {u'query': u'wed', u'suggestions': [], u'found': 0}}
```

Even when trying to use the AWS "Run a Test Search" tool with the suggester enabled it doesn't return any suggestions. I am assuming I've done something wrong in configuration but I'm not sure what as I have followed the AWS documentation during setup. I can't seem to find any resources around this feature, has anyone gotten this working successfully? I would really appreciate seeing a working example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the same thing happens to me, I already have documents indexed, I don`t know what else I have to do.

Comment: apardes - Did you get this working? Im learning cloudsearch and trying my best to get suggestions working but all i get is the same response as you shown in your question even if i try a word that i know exists at the start of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions starting from the beginning, if you have this title:

```
"Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace"
```

The suggester only works if you write the first word in this case: start.
but you start with the word: episode, this sugguester doesn't work, you need to index this sentence in many others, example three word suggestions.

```
   start wars episode
   wars episode I
   episode I the
   I the phantom
   the phantom Menace
```

If you do that, It will give suggestions starting from the beginning of any of the word groups.

Comment: Hey Israel can you elaborate on how you made this to work? I have configured a title field with fuzzy match high but I don't get any suggestions from the middle. What config do I need to change here?